# Casting Function Pointer to Integer in C++

Tags: c++

I have an array of unsigned integers that need to store pointers to data and functions as well as some data.  In the device I am working with, the sizeof pointer is the same as sizeof unsigned int.  How can I cast pointer to function into unsigned int?  I know that this makes the code not portable, but it is micro controller specific.  I tried this:

```
stackPtr[4] = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int>(task_ptr);
```

but it give me an error "invalid type conversion"

Casting it to void pointer and then to int is messy.

```
stackPtr[4] = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int>(static_cast<void *> (task_ptr));
```

Is there a clean way of doing it?

Edit - task_ptr is function pointer `void task_ptr(void)`

Love Barmar's answer, takes my portability shortcoming away.  Also array of void pointer actually makes more sense then Unsigned Ints.  Thank you Barmar and isaach1000.

EDIT 2:  Got it, my compiler is thinking large memory model so it is using 32 bit pointers not 16 bit that I was expecting (small micros with 17K total memory).

Comment: Can't you make the array an array of void pointers?

Comment: How about using a union of function pointers and data pointers?

Comment: A simple `reinterpret_cast` should work as long as (a) the integer type is large enough and (b) it's a pointer to a normal (non-member, or static member) function. Is that the case here? What exactly is `task_ptr`?

Comment: Wow, Barmar, that would make my code portable!  This is a major case of tunnel vision on my part. Thanks a million, your comment is worth 1000+

Comment: @user1135541 Remember the union ntrick is still illegal, it's just supported by more compilers.

Comment: `void(void)` isn't a pointer type, it's a function type. The corresponding pointer type is `void(*)(void)`.

Answer (score 4):

A C-style cast can fit an octogonal peg into a trapezoidal hole, so I would say that given your extremely specific target hardware and requirements, I would use that cast, possibly wrapped into a template for greater clarity.

Alternately, the double cast to `void*` and then `int` does have the advantage of making the code stand out like a sore thumb so your future maintainers know something's going on and can pay special attention.

EDIT for comment:
It appears your compiler may have a bug. The following code compiles on g++ 4.5:

```
#include <iostream>

int f()
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int value = (int)&f;

    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

EDIT2:
You may also wish to consider using the `intptr_t` type instead of `int`. It's an integral type large enough to hold a pointer.

Comment: The C++ compiler returns an error when I use C style cast:
    `Error[Pe171]: invalid type conversion`

Comment: Unfortunately, `intptr_t` is not specified to allow the reconstitution of converted function pointers the way it is for object pointers, and there is no equivalent for function pointers, either :-(.  So, there's no obvious way to ensure that your code will fail to compile on systems where function pointers won't fit in `intptr_t`.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ a pointer can be converted to a value of an integral type large enough to hold it. The conditionally-supported type `std::intptr_t` is defined such that you can convert a `void*` to `intptr_t` and back to get the original value. If `void*` has a size equal to or larger than function pointers on your platform then you can do the conversion in the following way.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cassert>

void foo() {}

int main() {
    void (*a)() = &foo;

    std::intptr_t b = reinterpret_cast<std::intptr_t>(a);

    void (*c)() = reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(b);
    assert(a==c);
}
```

Comment: It's also conditionally-supported whether or not `a` can be reinterpret-cast to `b`, even if `intptr_t` exists. (However it is guaranteed that if such support exists, then `a == c`).

Answer (score -1):

This is ansi compliant:

```
int MyFunc(void* p)
{
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
   int arr[2];
   int (*foo)(int*);

   arr[0] = (int)(MyFunc);

   foo = (int (*)(int*))(arr[0]);

   arr[1] = (*foo)(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Tried that, but my C++ complains, `invalid type conversion`.  Need a standard C++ way of doing it.

Comment: Last time I checked, `void main()` was non-standard.

Comment: I am using the IAR Embedded Workbench. `https://www.iar.com/en/Products/IAR-Embedded-Workbench/TI-MSP430/` but I think I know why it is not working, it is thinking of larger memory model then I am using, which makes the pointers 20bit instead of 16. So yes, you are right, its the compiler issue.  The MinGW compiler has no problems.